# In the PyTorch Distributed Data Parallel (DDP) tutorial, how does `setup` know it's rank?

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, distributed-system

For the tutorial [Getting Started with Distributed Data Parallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html)

How does `setup()` function knows the rank when `mp.spawn()` doesn't pass the rank?

```py
def setup(rank, world_size):
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '12355'

    # initialize the process group
    dist.init_process_group("gloo", rank=rank, world_size=world_size)
```

```py
def demo_basic(rank, world_size):
    print(f"Running basic DDP example on rank {rank}.")
    setup(rank, world_size)
    .......
```

```py
def run_demo(demo_fn, world_size):
    mp.spawn(demo_fn,
             args=(world_size,),
             nprocs=world_size,
             join=True)
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()
    assert n_gpus >= 2, f"Requires at least 2 GPUs to run, but got {n_gpus}"
    world_size = n_gpus
    run_demo(demo_basic, world_size)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mp.spawn` does pass the rank to the function it calls.

From the [`torch.multiprocessing.spawn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html#torch.multiprocessing.spawn) docs

> torch.multiprocessing.spawn(fn, args=(), nprocs=1, join=True, daemon=False, start_method='spawn')
>
> ...
>
> - fn (function) -
>
>   Function is called as the entrypoint of the spawned process. This
>   function must be defined at the top level of a module so it can be
>   pickled and spawned. This is a requirement imposed by multiprocessing. **The function is called as `fn(i, *args)`, where `i` is the process index
>   and `args` is the passed through tuple of arguments**.

So when `spawn` invokes `fn` it passes it the process index as the first argument.